# basename doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash, xargs, basename

How do I make ".mkv" disappear in the target filename?

```
$ echo a/b.mkv | xargs -I % echo ffmpeg -i "%" $(basename "%" ".mkv").mp4
ffmpeg -i a/b.mkv a/b.mkv.mp4
```

Comment: Why do you use echo and not directly `echo a/b.txt | xargs -I % basename "%" ".txt"`?

Comment: I changed the example to reflect what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I posted [a related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175987/) which led me to an ideal solution that avoids both xargs, sed and basename. Don't know if I should delete this post, then?

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to `basename` but to the fact that `basename "%" ".txt"` is executed too early. Try:

```
echo a/b.mkv | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo ffmpeg -i "%" $(basename "%" ".mkv").mp4'
```

The main goal of `basename` is to remove the directory part: the GNU basename(1) man page says: "strip directory and suffix from filenames"; so, it works as expected. If you want to keep the directory part:

```
echo a/b.mkv | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo ffmpeg -i "%" $(dirname "%")/$(basename "%" ".mkv").mp4'
```

There are other solutions such as with `sed`. For instance:

```
$ echo a/b.mkv | sed 's/\.mkv$/.mp4/'
a/b.mp4
```

Comment: Your solution addresses the problem, but removes the path of the target name. How do I keep the path?

Comment: @forthrin I assumed that you wanted to strip the directory part since this is the main goal of `basename`. I've edited my answer to do want you really want.