# Combining bash % with xargs %

Tags: bash, xargs

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664746) says you can use a `%` syntax to remove file extensions:

```
$ s=a/b.mkv
$ echo ${s%.*}
a/b
```

How do you combine the `%` syntax with the `%` in `xargs` to achieve the desired result for a set of lines?

```
$ cat | xargs -I % echo ffmpeg -i % (INSERT MAGIC HERE)
a/b.mkv
ffmpeg -i a/b.mkv a/b.mp4
c/d.mkv
ffmpeg -i c/d.mkv c/d.mp4
```

Comment: `s=a/b.mkv; echo ffmpeg -i "$s" "${s%.*}.mp4"`

Comment: Can you provide a solution that involves `xargs`? It needs to stay to accept multiple lines. I updated my initial posting.

Comment: There is no need to use `xargs` at all. `while true ; do read -r s ; echo ffmpeg -i "$s" "${s%.*}.mp4" ; done` But usually a liitle bit different syntax is used: `for s in files_list ; echo ffmpeg -i "$s" "${s%.*}.mp4" ; done`

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks! Is there any use for `xargs` at all, then?

Comment: @Costas please don't post answers as comments. If you do, the question will never be marked as answered.

Comment: Most of "true programmers" advised to avoid `eval` and `xargs` for security or some other reasons. But if you know exactly what are you doing you are welcome. `cat | xargs -I\& bash -c 's="&" ; echo ffmpeg -i "$s" "${s%.*}.mp4'`

Comment: @terdon But question is very simple...

Comment: @Costas for you, not for the OP :) Anyway, answering questions in comments is bad practice because it leaves the question s with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the comments given I was able to find a short and beautiful solution:

```
find . -name '*.mkv' | while read f; do echo ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Comment: In the case `for` is better `for f in $(find . -name '*.mkv') ; do echo ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.*}.mp4"; done`

Comment: @Costas why is `for` better? Unlike the while version of the OP, your `for` will break on any whitespace. Ideally, of course, you should use `find . -name '*.mkv' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do ... ; done` which can also deal with backslashes and newlines but at least don't use the `for f in $(find ...)` which can't even deal with simple spaces!

Comment: @terdon OK, you catch me. But OP can avoid problem with witespace just use `find . -name '*.mkv' -ls`

Comment: Not really @Costas. That is [not portable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) and also requires some tricky parsing to extract the file name. `-print0` is portable and easy to parse with `while`.

Comment: Yep, any solution that breaks with whitespace or other special characters is no good. So far my own suggestion stands as the best, as I'm not up for learning a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer, you could also use `zsh`. If this is your shell:

```
for i in **/*.mkv; echo ffmpeg -i $i $i:r.mp4
```

Otherwise:

```
zsh -c 'for i in **/*.mkv; echo ffmpeg -i $i $i:r.mp4'
```

This would avoid problems with whitespace in filenames.